# Do you have an idea on how to solve this kind of an issue "Maximum stack depth exceeded"?

Tags: laravel, api, httpresponse

This is the response
https://prnt.sc/12u1h6x
Here is the logic
https://prnt.sc/12u1iv7

Exceeded-maximum-stack-depth

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post all code and errors as text and not as screenshots.

Comment: You need to add more information here about the relation structure of the entities, the error could indicate e.g. a circular reference during serialization.

Answer (score 0):

This is the entity questions

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models\Questions;

use App\Models\Brand;
use App\Models\Questions\Choice\Traits\Attributes\QuestionAttribute;
use App\Models\Questions\Choice\Traits\Methods\QuestionMethod;
use App\Models\Questions\QuestionLink;
use App\Models\Questions\Choice\Choice;
use App\Models\Questions\Traits\ExtendedEloquentTrait;
use App\Models\Questions\Traits\Scopes\QuestionScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    use QuestionAttribute, QuestionMethod, ExtendedEloquentTrait, QuestionScope;

    protected $table = 'questions';

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $appends = [
        'question_name',
        'base_name',
        'is_loading',
        'is_english',
        'is_italian',
        'is_german',
        'is_bisaya',
        'is_filipino',
        'translated_question',
        'locale_question',
        'has_succeeding_questions',
    ];

    public function question_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(QuestionType::class, 'type');
    }

    public function question_links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(QuestionLink::class, 'question');
    }

    /**
     * The questions that belong to the brand.
     */
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Brand::class, 'brand_questions', 'questions', 'brand');
    }

    /**
     * The questions that belong to the choices.
     */
    public function choice()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Choice::class, 'question_links', 'question', 'choice')->withPivot('succeeding');
    }

    public function questionnaire_contents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(QuestionnaireContent::class, 'question_id');
    }
}
```

and This is my choice entity/model

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models\Questions\Choice;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Questions\Choice\Traits\Attributes\ChoiceAttribute;
use App\Models\Questions\Choice\Traits\Methods\ChoiceMethod;
use App\Models\Questions\Choice\Traits\Scopes\ChoiceScope;
use App\Models\Questions\Question;


class Choice extends Model
{
  use ChoiceAttribute, ChoiceMethod, ChoiceScope;

  protected $table = 'choices';
    
  protected $guarded = [];

  protected $appends = [
      'choice_name',
      'has_translation',
      'base_name',
      'is_loading',
      'is_english',
      'is_italian',
      'is_german',
      'is_bisaya',
      'is_filipino',
      'on_select_choice_name'
  ];

  public function questionLinks()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(QuestionLink::class, 'choice');
  }

  /**
   * The choice that belong to the questions.
   */
  public function questions()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'question_links', 'choice', 'question');
  } 
}
```